# Dart BoundSinkStream exception

Tags: dart, flutter

I was experimenting with flutter recently. Tried to display some data in order to test flutter`s ui concept. However, whenever I want to call rest for something, it cames back with strange exception (it's hard to read for me).

Below is a sample code (mostly from https://flutter.io/networking/)

```
 loadData(String url) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(url);
    var request = await httpClient.getUrl(uri);
    var response = await request.close();
    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
      var responseBody = await response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();

      await print(responseBody);
    }
  }
```

and the exception it returns:

```
type '_BoundSinkStream<dynamic, List<int>>' is not a subtype of type '_HttpIncoming' where
_BoundSinkStream is from dart:async
List is from dart:core
int is from dart:core
List is from dart:core
int is from dart:core
_HttpIncoming is from dart:_http
List is from dart:core
int is from dart:core
#0_HttpClientResponse.listen (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:382:23)
#1new _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:49:16)
#2_BoundSinkStream.listen (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:185:13)
#3Stream.join (dart:async/stream.dart:741:25)
#4HttpConnector.loadData (package:flutter_app/providers/HttpConnector.dart:26:63)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5WeatherProvider.loadWeather (package:flutter_app/providers/WeatherProvider.dart:12:42)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6 _MyHomePageState._loadData (file:///Users/krzysztofbalana/Private/flutter_app/lib/main.dart:64:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a type mismatch depending on how you are structuring and getting the data. I have a created a dummy example that may help you along:

```
class FakeApi extends StatelessWidget {
  _loadData() async{
    String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    var httpClinet = createHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClinet.get(url);
    var _myRequest = JSON.decode(response.body);
    print(_myRequest);
    print(_myRequest[0]);
    ///so forth

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: _loadData,child: new Text("Fetch"),),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hm, still the same error. I've even created new project and tried to run dumbest call :   void loadData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/10"),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    );
    print(response.body);
  }. "http" from import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Comment: I've took example from that place: https://github.com/bramvbilsen/Flutter-HTTP-Requests-REST-api/blob/master/lib/main.dart and still no luck. Can this be a problem with project configuration maybe? Inside "Project Structure" (Android Studio 3.0.1) there's a note about some problems - https://imgur.com/a/34TH3